# How can I get the list of registered interfaces and their GUIDs in a Delphi 2007 application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I want to get a list of interfaces registered in a Delphi 2007 application (with code from within that application) in order to check for possible duplicate GUIDs.

There is a solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/zensan/pascal.today/blob/master/uInterfaces.Duplicates.pas) which uses the System.RTTI unit, but unfortunately that unit is not available in Delphi 2007.

Is it possible to do without?

EDIT:
I'm mostly interested in those interfaces that are declared in my own application, because there duplicate GUIDs are most likely due to cut and paste. It wouldn't hurt to get them system wide so I could find interfaces I declared which conflict with others in the system, but that's much less likely.

With "registered" I mean interfaces that can be used in an "as" expression like this:

```
SomeInterfaceVariable := SomeOhterInterfaceVariable as ISomeInterface;
```

I am aware that the interfaces which won't result in runtime errors depend on what the implementing object supports, but I think there must be a list somewhere containing all possible interfaces (and the code linked above suggests that I am right).

Comment: What do you mean by registered?

Comment: What kind of interfaces are you interested in exactly? Regular Delphi interfaces, COM interfaces? Only inside your app, global to the OS? Please be more specific.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: I am not sure about 2007 version but most likely It is possible but non trivial. System.Rtti using GetPackageInfoTable for traversing types. This function retrieve types information inside package.

Comment: @dummzeuch What makes you think there is "a list somewhere containing all possible interfaces"?  When you invoke an `as` (or `Supports()`) operation, the compiler sees the interface you are requesting, extracts its guid directly from its declaration, and generates runtime code to query the target interface for that guid and obtain a pointer to it.  No global list in the compiled app is needed to perform that at runtime, it is a fairly static operation.

Comment: @dummzeuch That being said, IF you can obtain a list of old-stye RTTI for available interfaces (which you are going to hunt for manually), the `TTypeData::IntfGuid` field does contain an interface's GUID when `TTypeInfo.Kind == tkInterface`.

Comment: Probably to be 100% reliable you'll need to parse all of the source code. Which actually isn't that difficult.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the code I linked in the question made me think that such a list exists or can be created, because it obviously retrieves it.

Comment: @dummzeuch that code uses Enhanced RTTI, which was added in D2010. Before that, the old style RTTI was available only for published properties of classes, and interfaces declared with `{$M+}`. But there is no global list generated, but you can query specific types

Comment: @RemyLebeau `{$M+}` is short for `{$METHODINFO ON}` and has little to do with the basic PTypeInfo and the typedata which contains the guid for interface types. Even without that you can scan the specific typeinfo tables in the binary.

Comment: @StefanGlienke per the [Compiler Directives](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Compiler_Directives_(List)_Index) documentation, `{$M}` is the short switch for [`{$TYPEINFO}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Run-Time_Type_Information_(Delphi)), not for [`{$METHODINFO}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/METHODINFO_directive_(Delphi)), which has no short switch. `{$TYPEINFO}`/`{$M(+|-)}` controls whether or not RTTI is generated at all, including interface guids. `{$METHODINFO}` controls whether or not extended RTTI is generated for interface methods.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Both have nothing to do with basic TTypeInfo generated into the binary however (and even with $RTTI turning every enhanced RTTI off will not affect this) - check for yourself. If the type is in the binary somehow (either referenced as part of another public type or using {$STRONGLINKTYPES ON} it is part of the typeinfo table - I just don't know if this was already the case before the introduction of enhanced RTTI in Delphi 2010.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I can't check for myself, my computer died a week ago and I don't have Delphi installed right now. But based on the documentation, an interface doesn't generate even basic RTTI unless it is declared in the `{$M+}` state, or derives from an interface that is, like [`IInvokable`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IInvokable): "*The {$M+} compiler option ensures that the interface and all its descendants include RTTI.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah we all know how trustworthy that doc is... You might know how much I work with RTTI - you only need to put `{$M+}` on interfaces (or inherit from `IInvokable`) when you need info on its methods - to create dynamic proxies and that. Every public type gets typeinfo generated by default. You cannot entirely turn it off - only the extended info for fields, methods and properties on classes and records can.

Comment: @StefanGlienke "*You might know how much I work with RTTI*" - I don't, actually.